# Find the n values whose sum is equal to 2020

Tags: r

I have a vector `Vec` with these values:

```
1721
979
366
299
675
1456
```

I am struggling in finding a way to obtain which combination of `n` (I would like to do initially for `n=2`) values has a sum equals to 2020.

In the example is easy to see this as 1721 and 299 sum 2020 but my data is even longer and I would like to generalize to `n` values so that I have a function where I set a vector and a value to choose the combination of numbers (it can be 2,3,5,..). My output would be `c(1721,299)`.

Comment: Advent of Code?

Comment: Take a look at the `combn` function - for example, `combn(Vec, 2)` will give you all the different two-element combinations of `Vec`

Comment: To generalize your problem you will have to minimize the absolute value of the difference between the target value and sum of n numbers.  Which will require an optimization formulation if you don't use brute force exhaustive enumeration.

Answer (score 4):

You can get all combinations of your input numbers with `combn()`, which returns a matrix where the combinations are columns. So then you just need to take the sum of each column and see which one is equal to your target.

```
Vec <- c(1721,
  979,
  366,
  299,
  675,
  1456)
n <- 2

all_combinations <- combn(Vec,n)
all_combinations[,colSums(all_combinations) == 2020]
```

Answer (score 3):

***Note***: Benchmarks at [this gist](https://gist.github.com/mrdwab/98ccff650ef52da56144026f493a33a0). Note also the memory allocation on each approach.

---

#### Update

For a faster version of the `combn` recommendation, check out `comboGeneral` from the "RcppAlgos" package:

```
fun_RcppAlgos <- function(x, target, n) {
  a <- RcppAlgos::comboGeneral(x, n)
  a[which(rowSums(a) == target), ]
}
```

---

For `n = 2`, *and assuming that you're only expecting one pair to be returned*, the solution is as simple as:

```
Vec[(2020 - Vec) %in% Vec]
## [1] 1721  299
```

For `n = 3`, my initial thought was to use `combn` or `expand.grid` (or `data.table::CJ`), but then I thought this might also be a good case for a `for` loop. Since I don't use `for` loops a lot, here's what I came up with:

```
fun_for <- function(x, target, n) {
  if (!n %in% c(2, 3)) stop("The accounting Elves are crazy!")
  if (n == 2) {
    out <- x[(target - x) %in% x]
  } else if (n == 3) {
    out <- numeric(0)
    for (i in seq_along(x)) {
      s1 <- x + x[i]
      for (j in seq_along(s1)) {
        s2 <- s1 + x[j]
        if (any(s2 == target)) out <- c(out, x[which(s2 == target)])
      }
    }
    out <- unique(out)
  }
  out
}
```

And, for `expand.grid` and `data.table::CJ`, these were the functions I used:

```
fun_eg <- function(x, target, n) {
  a <- expand.grid(replicate(n, x, FALSE))
  unlist(a[rowSums(a) == target, ][1, ], use.names = FALSE)
}

fun_cj <- function(x, target, n) {
  a <- do.call(data.table::CJ, replicate(n, x, FALSE))
  unlist(a[rowSums(a) == target, ][1, ], use.names = FALSE)
}
```

The reason I'm *extremely* hesitant about the `expand.grid` type approach is that you can quickly end up having to generate a ***huge*** table against which you're going to be checking. For example, with `length(x) == 500`, you'd have to create a table with 125,000,000 rows and 3 columns that you're going to have to check against.

`combn` is a bit better. With `combn`, if you have `length(x) == 500`, you'd have to create a matrix with 3 rows and 10,586,800 columns (run `choose(400, 3)` to calculate the number of columns).

Keeping all of that in mind, I ran some tests, which I've posted [at this gist](https://gist.github.com/mrdwab/98ccff650ef52da56144026f493a33a0) (rather than crowding this post further). This is one of those cases where a `for` loop makes sense, and if you continue with the Advent of Code 2020 problems, you're probably going to have to practice your looping and recursion skills a lot. Have fun!

Comment: Nice answer. FYI, you can get the answer more efficiently using `comboGeneral`. Simply specifying `constraintFun = "sum"``, `comparisonFun = "==", and `limitConstraints = 2020`. See https://jwood000.github.io/RcppAlgos/articles/SubsetSum.html#partitions-with-no-restrictions for more information.  Btw, I'm the author.

Comment: I made the changes I suggested above and reran your benchmarks and got around 115 times faster on the last example. Before adding those parameters the median time for `fun_RcppAlgos(x, 2020, 3)` was around `25ms`. After, it was only `30 microsecond`.

Comment: @JosephWood, I'll have to check out your suggested changes. Great package!

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to find one solution (there might be multiple solution) for the [subset sum problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem), you could try `subsetsum` from package `adagio`

```
> adagio::subsetsum(Vec, 2020)
$val
[1] 2020

$inds
[1] 1 4
```

such that

```
> Vec[adagio::subsetsum(Vec, 2020)$inds]
[1] 1721  299
```

---

Another way is using `combn`, e.g.,

```
f <- function(Vec, Tar, n) {
  Filter(
    length,
    combn(Vec, n, FUN = function(x) ifelse(sum(x) == Tar, list(x), list(NULL)))
  )
}
```

where a function `f` is defined for the objective, such that

```
> f(Vec,2020,2)
[[1]]
[1] 1721  299

> f(Vec,2020,3)
[[1]]
[1] 979 366 675
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using very basic coding.

```
Sub <- list()
for(x in vec){
 Sub[[as.character(x)]] <- 2020-x
  
if(Sub[[as.character(x)]] %in% vec){print(paste0(x,",",Sub[[as.character(x)]]))}
}
```